# The images are missing for download html data

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, offline

We use the code to download the wikipedia html data and save it.

```
    NSString *urlString = @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adele";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if ([data length] >0 && error == nil){
             NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:html forKey:urlString];
             NSLog(@"Downloaded.");
         }
         else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil){
             NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");
         }
         else if (error != nil){
             NSLog(@"Error happened = %@ /n %@", error, urlString);

             [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(updateTextFaild) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
         }

     }];
```

Then we turn the device or simulator offline and open the download html data with UIWebView. However, there are something missing (images) for the download wikipedia data. 
We use the code to open the data:(the "_urlString" is "@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adele"")

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:_urlString])
{
    [_webview loadHTMLString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:_urlString] baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_urlString]];
    return;
}
```

It's so strange.

Comment: Since you downloaded the HTML only this is normal. You will need to parse the HTML get all the image link in the document and download each images as well.

Comment: Wow, that's might be complex. Is there anything more better way to resolve the problem?